# Cumsum ignoring NA's with reset

Tags: r, cumsum

I have conditional sum with reset at zero.

```
criteria1 <- c(rep(0,2), rep(1,5), rep(0,3), rep(1,6),rep(0,2))
criteria1[c(6,9,12,13,14,15)] <- NA

#cumsum function, working before the first NA
ave(criteria1, cumsum(criteria1 == 0), FUN = cumsum )
[1]  0  0  1  1  1 NA  1  0 NA  0  1 NA NA NA NA  1  0  0

#and desired output would be
#NA's are replaced with the last value accumulated
#if more than three leave NA's in 
0 0 1 2 3 3 4 0 0 0 1 NA NA NA NA 2 0 0
```

Some conditions:

- `NA`s can not be replaced with zero(or one),
- vector must remain the same length (so excluding is not an option)
- longest length of consecutive ignored `NA`s should be three. If it is more than three, then they should remain as `NA`s and function should continue from the last non `NA`.

Some answers exist on the same topic, but I am not sure how to put it all together.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `?na.locf` from `zoo`.

Comment: what needs to happen when there are 4 consecutive `NA` values?

Comment: "longest length of consecutive ignored NAs should be three." -- you should probably extend your example so that this condition actually matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With R base you can do:
generate data

```
criteria1 <- c(rep(0,2), rep(1,5), rep(0,3), rep(1,6),rep(0,2))
criteria1[c(6,9,12,13)] <- NA
```

get result

```
l <- length(criteria1)
cum <- cumsum(ifelse(!is.na(criteria1),criteria1,0))
zero <- which(criteria1 == 0)

res <- cum - rep(cum[zero], c(zero[2:length(zero)],l+1)-zero)
```

optional dplyr solution:

```
res <- cum - rep(cum[zero], dplyr::coalesce(dplyr::lead(zero),l+1L)-zero)
```

detect and change repeats of NA > 3 times

```
NAs <- rle(is.na(criteria1))
NAloc <- which(NAs$lengths > 3 & NAs$values == 1)
for(i in NAloc)
{
res[seq(sum(NAs$lengths[1:(i-1)])+1,sum(NAs$lengths[1:i]))] <- NA
}
```

Comment: Looks good, it just doesn't break after it reaches >3 missing values.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by 'break'. 
Does the vector end before the 3 NA's ? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Since `NA`s are treated as zero when summed up but they are grouped as if they have the same value as previous values, you can treat `NA` differently based on the logic in the value variable and group variable within `ave`:

```
library(data.table); library(dplyr); library(zoo);

ave(coalesce(criteria1, 0), rleid(na.locf(criteria1 != 0)), FUN = cumsum)
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 3 4 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 3 4 0 0
```